# Blender 2.79 and 2.78c crash on startup with Exception access violation error

Tags: python, installation

I've been trying to install blender 2.79 on my windows 10 machine but it crashes on start up and shows the error bellow :

[image]

I tried changing the sound properties but it did not work, I updated my graphics card drivers, I tried installing a previous version of blender (2.78c) but I kept getting the same error, I tried installing the 32 bit and 64 bit version but the problem persists, I uninstalled every instance of python i have installed, deactivated my firewall... I even tried debugging it and i got this

[image]

I also tried the `--factory-startup` option but i got the same results as the debug case so i tried using the  latest build version with `--factory-startup`
[image]
This is trully frustrating and I really need it for work so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried running as administrator?

Comment: Yes, it still crashes

Comment: What have you tried so far apart from what you wrote? There are a lot google results that will tell you exactly what we will

Comment: I tried updating my graphics card drivers and i logged out of my microsoft account, both of these also didn't work

Comment: Try `--factory-startup`

Comment: Where are you downloading blender from? Is the version in last screenshot same as in prior?  Can you post result of factory startup and debug together.

Comment: Sometimes I've seen that error when Windows defender has decided that the program in question is 'dangerous'. If you have Defender enabled, you can open WIndows Defender Security Center, select App & Browser control, and look at the setting for check apps and files.  If it's set to block, defender may have blocked blender without telling you. This URL has an explanation on how to unblock: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-security/how-do-you-add-a-program-to-allowed-items-in/7f5c2ded-394a-40f4-bbe7-762fdd716a2f

Comment: sorry, the URL I posted was wrong and it's too late to edit my comment.